# Adobe Illustrator Pathfinder Outline problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to make same steps as mentioned in tutorial? First picture is mine other are from tutorial I made shape and the graph with brush then Pathfinder + Outline, but it's just blank.

[image: this is what i get]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you select pathfinder < outline you will need to select a stroke color and give it a stroke weight before it becomes visible.